# Why am I getting an error on flutter android when attempting to use firebase services such as OTP and Dynamic Linking?

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, flutter-dependencies

Whenever I try to use any Firebase service, I get the following error and only on android. My SHA1 and 256 keys are configured, I have the google-services.json in the correct place. No problems come in my flutter doctor. I am at a complete loss for how to solve this.

The fact that the problem only comes on android makes me think that it is something wrong with the configuration of the android on Firebase but I've redone the process many times. Any help would be much appreciated, if you would like to see any other relevant information, let me know.

````
W/GmsClient(29923): IGmsServiceBroker.getService failed
W/GmsClient(29923): android.os.DeadObjectException: Transaction failed on small parcel; remote process probably died, but this could also be caused by running out of binder buffe
W/GmsClient(29923):     at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
W/GmsClient(29923):     at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(BinderProxy.java:584)
W/GmsClient(29923):     at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzac.getService(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.0.0:8)
W/GmsClient(29923):     at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.BaseGmsClient.getRemoteService(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.0.0:14)
W/GmsClient(29923):     at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zabt.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.0.1:7)
W/GmsClient(29923):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
W/GmsClient(29923):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
W/GmsClient(29923):     at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
W/GmsClient(29923):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
W/GmsClient(29923):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)```
````

Comment: Do you get this issue only on your Virtual Android device or also in your physical Android device?

Comment: I only get this issue on my android vm, but I don't own an android phone myself so this is a problem for me. I am using a Mac m1 which might be part of the issue.

Comment: I have the same issue, but I can't fix it